# Проблема с датой в UTC

Tags: javascript, время

Создается приложение с погодой. В ответе на запрос мне приходят данные с текущим временем в формате unix, UTC. Мой часовой пояс киевский, то есть UTC+3. Сейчас 17:08, я отправляю запрос и получаю текущее время "1589810900", создаю экземпляр объекта Date (new Date(1589810900 * 1000)), время в котором  16:08, как будто мой часовой пояс UTC+1.  Видимо я что-то не так понимаю, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Comment: `console.log(new Date())` что у Вас пишет?

Comment: Mon May 18 2020 17:26:53 GMT+0200 (Восточная Европа, стандартное время)

Comment: Ну так, если у Вас в системе стоит часовой пояс GMT +2, как оно должно догадаться, что Вам нужно +3? :)

Comment: Действительно) Исправил в системе, теперь все корректно. Спасибо